# JavaScript --- How can I make a rule to make sure a user entered a value between two specific numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

How can I make sure a user entered a value between two numbers on a form? In this instance, one of the boxes asks the user to enter their GPA. I need to ensure that the number is between 0 and 4. They cannot click the submit button until the number is between 0 and 4.

Can I do something like:

```
GPA: {
min: 0,
max: 4
}
```

If you look at the code below I already have one rule (Student ID input box is required)... How can I incorporate the GPA rule in there?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#studentID').focus();
//validate form
$('#tuition').validate({
rules: {
    studentID: {
        required: true,
    }
},//end rules

messages: {
    studentID: {
        required: "Please enter your student ID.",
    }
},//end messages    

});//end validate

//School auto-complete
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [`range`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/range-method/) option

```
$('#tuition').validate({
    rules: {
        studentID: {
            required: true,
        },
        GPA: {
            range : [0, 4]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        studentID: {
            required: "Please enter your student ID."
        },
        GPA: {
            range: "Please enter a number between 0 and 4."
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you! 
I tried rangelength: [0,4] 
I'm obviously a beginner

Comment: @JeffDoe, why didn't you try the code you mentioned in the top of your question?  `GPA: { min: 0, max: 4 }` would have also worked fine.

Comment: `range` is not an "option"... it's a "method"...  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/#range-method

Comment: I did try the: 
GPA: { min: 0, max: 4 }, but it wasn't working.

Comment: @JeffDoe, Strange.  Works for me.  See:  [min](https://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method/) and [max](https://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method/) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need Javascript here, just use `min` and `max` attributes in your `input` tag like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="4" />
```

Comment: The OP is asking about how to use the jQuery Validation plugin... not how to use HTML5 validation rules.

Comment: @Sparky, sure, the OP can use any method that he likes, i just offered another way